# Loading html content at a certain location hash using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I loaded html content onclick in a div using javascript. The problem is I want the loaded content to be at a certain position based on a given hash.

I'm able to load all the html content inside the div. The content is displayed starting from the top as normal. I want the content to be in a certain position for a given hash. Like in the middle of the loaded content.

```
$("#divToLoadContent").load(link);
```

Using the `window.location.hash` does not work because the url does not change.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First load the content the way you want to. Then redirect user to that hash location with `location.hash = "destination_hash"`. Remember to clear hash every time you want user to be redirected to destination hash using `location.hash = ""`

```js
$("#loadnow").click(function(){
    $("#divToLoadContent").html("<br/><br/>use load() instead of html()<br/><br/>");
    location.hash = "";
    location.hash = "contenthash";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="loadnow" value="Try"/>
<div style="background:lightblue;height:500px;padding:20px;"> Just a placeholder </div>
<a id="contenthash"></a>
<div id="divToLoadContent"></div>
<div style="background:pink;height:500px;padding:20px;"> Just a placeholder </div>
```

**EDIT**

The code above navigates your user to `#contenthash` once the content is loaded (`#contenthash` already existed before the new content was loaded)

However, after @IronFlare's comment, the code below will take your user to `#contenthash` which didn't exist before the content was loaded

```js
$("#loadnow").click(function(){
    var example_content = '<div style="background:lightblue;height:1000px;"></div><a id="contenthash"></a>OKAY, IF you are seeing this, you\'re at #contenthash <div style="background:pink;height:500px;"></div>';
    $("#divToLoadContent").html(example_content);
    location.hash = "";
    location.hash = "contenthash";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="loadnow" value="Try Now"/>
<div id="divToLoadContent"></div>
```

Comment: I interpreted the author's question not as wanting to scroll the viewport to the loaded content, but rather to scroll the loaded content within its div to a specific landmark in the loaded page. The question is vague but I don't think it's asking about how to scroll the outer viewport.

Comment: @IronFlare, I am sorry I misunderstood. I just added new code which takes user to specific point `hash` of `new content` that was just loaded

Comment: No problem at all-- I'm not sure I'm getting it completely, either. [Here's a diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK8kd.png) of what I think the asker is describing.

Comment: Thank you! `location.hash = ""; location.hash = "contenthash";` did the trick! @IronFlare interpreted my question the correct way and @LIGHT edit code worked!

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do this using `jQuery.load`.

The quickest way to accomplish what you're trying to do would be to use an [`iFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) instead. `iFrames` allow you to load the contents of another page inside an element, but allow that loaded page to run on its own, sandboxed from the surrounding page.

Because they're essentially a separate page, `iFrames` have a scrollbar which you can manipulate programmatically. Alternatively, you might even be able to scroll to a location automatically based on the URL's hash.